# Covariance of a vectorized random matrix

Tags: variance, covariance, covariance-matrix, random-matrix

I am looking for an answer to the following question. Assume a *random matrix* $\mathbf{A}$ of dimension $n\times n$ such that each row $\mathbf{A}_i$ of the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is a realization of a multivariate normal distribution $\mathcal{N}_n(\mathbf{0},\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{i})$. It follows that \begin{equation}vec(\mathbf{A}^\intercal)\sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0},\boldsymbol{\Sigma}),\end{equation} where $vec(\cdot)$ corresponds to the vectrorization operator, and $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ is a $n^2 \times n^2$ block diagonal matrix with $n$ blocks of dimension $n\times n$ on its diagonal with the $i$th block being $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{i}$.

The problem is that the covariance in a matrix Normal distribution of a random $n\times n$ matrix is characterized by two $n\times n$ matrices, describing row and column covariances respectively. In my case, the row covariance matrix is $\mathbf{I}_{n\times n}$ due to the row independence, however, the column covariance instead of being a $n\times n$ matrix is an $n^2\times n^2$ block diagonal.

My question is what is the variance-covariance matrix of the random matrix $\mathbf{A}$ if the covariance of $vec(\mathbf{A}^\intercal)$ is $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}=\text{bdiag}(\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^1,\dots,\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^n)$? Is there any nice linear algebra solution to write this down?

Comment: The answer is immediate, because you have all the information about covariances at your fingertips, assuming (as is implicit in the question) that the rows are *independent.* That implies the covariances between the entries in different rows are zero.  The only thing left to do is to write this down in any form you find convenient.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find 
information on how to do this in the **My Account** 
section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.